# Process exited before completing request - AWS Lambdas

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS Lambdas to try and connect to a CMS and i've encountered the following error:

> Process exited before completing request

Here's my snippet below:

```
require('dotenv').config({ silent: true });
const contentful = require('contentful');

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  const client = contentful.createClient({
    space: process.env.SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.CDA_TOKEN
  })
  client.getEntries({
    'content_type': 'thumbnail'
  })
  .then(function (entries) {
    context.succeed(JSON.stringify(entries));
    })
};
```

Does this error suggest that i'm getting an error somewhere in my code that's preventing it from running context.succeed or that i'm using context.succeed incorrectly?

Comment: There should be more to the error message. Please look at the CloudWatch logs. It could be that you have configured your lambda timeout that is low and your function couldn't finish its execution within that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Process exited before completing request

It means that you got an unhandled exception. Your handler basically crashed without telling Lambda why.

Looking at your code, it is most likely that the `client.getEntries()` promise got rejected and you didn't provide a `.catch()` to your promise.

You can do the following instead...

```
// Use callback coz context.succeed() is soooo legacy.
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const client = contentful.createClient({
    space: process.env.SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.CDA_TOKEN
  })

  return client.getEntries({
    'content_type': 'thumbnail'
  })
  // Be consistent with arrow function usage.
  .then((entries) => callback(null, JSON.stringify(entries)))
  // This is what is missing.
  .catch((err) => {
    // Log the error so you know what it is and fix it.
    console.error(err);
    // Be polite and tell Lambda that the invocation failed.
    callback(err);
  });
};
```